# An elementary mapping can be extended to an elementary embedding

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

> Let $\mathcal A,\mathcal B$ be $\mathcal L$-structures, where $A$ is finite. Let $f$ be a partial elementary embedding from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathcal{B}$. Then $\mathcal A \simeq \mathcal B$, i.e. there exists an extension of $f$ to an isomorphism from $\mathcal A$ to $\mathcal B$. In particular, $\mathcal A\equiv \mathcal B\Rightarrow \mathcal A\simeq\mathcal B$.

I intend to show the existence of the extension by induction. Assume $X=dom(f)\subsetneq A$ and $a\in A$, then I need to find $b\in B$ such that $f\cup \{(a,b)\}$ is an $(\mathcal A,\mathcal B)$-elementary mapping. However I do not know how to continue using $A$ is finite.

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Some of your notation is nonstandard. By $|A| < \infty$ you mean that $A$ is finite right? If so, then it is better to write $|A| < \aleph_0$ or $|A| < \omega$ (or just "$A$ is finite"). The domain of $f$ can be any subset of $A$, right? And finally, $\simeq$ is usually used for some sort of equivalence or isomorphism, which is stronger than just an elementary embedding (although not for finite structures, which probably is the point of this exercise).

Comment: @MarkKamsma Thank you very much for the comment and I would highly appreciate if you could edit the question since I am really new to the field of mathematical logic...

Comment: I edited, please double check if this is indeed the question you had in mind.

Comment: @MarkKamsma Thanks! Is it necessary to require $f:A\to B$ is bijective? The statement I had just says there should exist an extension of $f$ to an elementary embedding.

Comment: We do not require it, you can actually prove it! So that might be a nice little exercise in between: if $f: A \to B$ is an elementary embedding and $A$ is finite, can you prove that $f$ must actually be an isomorphism?

Comment: @MarkKamsma Yes, because if $A$ is finite, then it is not possible to pick pairwise distinct elements from $A$ of more than its cardinality. Since $f$ is an elementary embedding, in $B$ the same sentence also hold, so $B$ is also finite, thus $f$ is bijective.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right: in a finite structure the first-order sentences define the entire structure. Can you use a similar trick to extend the partial map?

Comment: @MarkKamsma I am not sure I understand your hint. If I want to find such a sentence (maybe containing $\exists$), it should be true in the expansion of $\mathcal A$ by $X=dom(f)$, but I am yet to show $f$ is elementary on $dom(f)\cup \{a\}$, so I can not derive such a sentence hold in $\mathcal B_X$, too. Then what does it help to find such a sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f: X \to B$, with $C \subseteq A$, be a partial elementary map. If $C = A$, we have nothing to do, otherwise we pick $a \in A - C$ and we will extend $f$ to $C \cup \{a\}$. As discussed in the comments: $A$ and $B$ must have the same cardinality, because we can write down a first-order sentence specifying the cardinality of the structures (since they are finite). So $B - f(C) = \{b_1, \ldots, b_n\}$ must also be non-empty and finite. We now show that there must be $1 \leq i \leq n$ such that $B \models \phi(b_i, f(\bar{c}))$ for all $\phi(x, \bar{y})$ and tuples $\bar{c}$ in $C$, such that $A \models \phi(a, \bar{c})$. The reason is that then we can set $f(a) = b_i$. Suppose not, then for every $1 \leq i \leq n$, there is some $\phi_i(x, \bar{y_i})$ such that $B \not \models \phi_i(b_i, f(\bar{c_i}))$ for some tuple $\bar{c_i}$ in $C$, while $A \models \phi_i(a, \bar{c_i})$. Now consider the formula:
$$
\psi(x) = \bigwedge_{1 \leq i \leq n} \phi_i(x, \bar{c_i}) \wedge \bigwedge_{c \in C} x \neq c.
$$
By construction we have $A \models \exists x \psi(x)$ while $B \not \models \exists x \psi(x)$ (where we replace each $c \in C$ with $f(c)$), which contradicts $f$ being elementary.

We can thus extend $f$ to $C \cup \{a\}$, then repeating this process extends $f$ to all of $A$. As mentioned before, $|A| = |B|$, so any injective function $A \to B$ will be a bijection, and an elementary embedding that is a bijection is an isomorphism. So we conclude that indeed $A \simeq B$.

Finally, for the last remark: if $A \equiv B$ then the empty map $f: \emptyset \to B$ is a partial elementary embedding (nowhere did we require $C$ to be non-empty). By the above we can extend that to an isomorphism, so $A \simeq B$.

Comment: Thank you very much!